# Arrows between arrows

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

Here is a fragment from MacLane's classic book "Categories for the working mathematician":

[image: Two natural transformations between two pairs of functors]

Here is another one that's a bit more complicated:

[image: Four natural transformations between six functors]

Is there a package that allows to (hopefully easily) typeset things of this kind?

PS: I've been using several packages for making commutative diagrams (amscd, tikz-cd), which is enough for a lot of stuff in category theory. But the picture above isn't really a "commutative diagram", it's something else. I don't even know how to call it, so looking it up on the web is kind of problematic. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to typeset it directly with Latex, or could you draw it, and include it as a graphic?  With tools like Metapost, Asymptote, etc you can draw anything with arrows and labels (hopefully easily).

Comment: @Thruston Ideally, I'd like to use it directly with Latex, and in such a way that it displays correctly when compiling to dvi and then producing an image with dvipng. This would let me add these diagrams to Anki flashcards without changing my workflow and/or tinkering with the depths of Anki (which uses latex + dvipng).

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! I'm surprised there's no shorter way, and such that would let me avoid mentioning any specific sizes/shifts/scale factors/etc :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my version also using `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
C \ar[shift left=7pt, ""{name=UL, below}]{r}{S} \ar[shift right=7pt, ""name=LL]{r}[swap]{T\vphantom{'}} &
B \ar[shift left=7pt, ""{name=UR, below}]{r}{S'} \ar[shift right=7pt, ""name=LR]{r}[swap]{T'} &
A\\
\ar[from=UL, to=LL, "r", shorten <= -2pt, shorten >= -2pt]
\ar[from=UR, to=LR, "r\smash{'}", shorten <= -2pt, shorten >= -2pt]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}
C \ar[shift left=10pt, ""{name=UL, below}]{r} \ar[shift right=10pt, ""name=LL]{r} \ar[""name=ML, ""{name=MLL, below}]{r} &
B \ar[shift left=10pt, ""{name=UR, below}]{r} \ar[shift right=10pt, ""name=LR]{r} \ar[""name=MR, ""{name=MLR, below}]{r} &
A\\
\ar[from=UL, to=ML, "\sigma", shorten <= -3pt, shorten >= -3pt]
\ar[from=UR, to=MR, "\sigma\smash{'}", shorten <= -3pt, shorten >= -3pt]
\ar[from=MLL, to=LL, "\tau", shorten <= -3pt, shorten >= -3pt]
\ar[from=MLR, to=LR, "\tau\smash{'}", shorten <= -3pt, shorten >= -3pt]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. Also proves that I know nothing about tikz-cd.

Comment: Glad you like it. tikz-cd can do a lot of things for you especially as you can insert any TikZ stuff you want.

Comment: Too bad tikz-cd doesn't seem to work in my current setting (I'm forced to use latex + dvipng, and arrows simply don't show up). But this is useful anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use tikz-cd for this kind of diagrams. For example, use

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
%% Hint for the positions: L=left, R=right, U=up D=down
  \begin{tikzcd}
    C \arrow[bend left=80]{r}[name=LUU, below]{}
    \arrow{r}[name=LUD]{}
    \arrow[swap]{r}[name=LDU]{}
    \arrow[bend right=80]{r}[name=LDD]{}
    \arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(LUU) -- (LUD)\tikztonodes]{r}{\sigma}
    \arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(LDU) -- (LDD)\tikztonodes]{r}{\tau}
    & 
    B
    \arrow[bend left=80]{r}[name=RUU, below]{}
    \arrow{r}[name=RUD]{}
    \arrow[swap]{r}[name=RDU]{}
    \arrow[bend right=80]{r}[name=RDD]{}
    \arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(RUU) -- (RUD)\tikztonodes]{r}{\sigma'}
    \arrow[Rightarrow,to path=(RDU) -- (RDD)\tikztonodes]{r}{\tau'}
    & A
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution using MetaPost could look something like this:

```
u:=1.8cm; % Horizontal scale
s:=6pt; % shift from letters
h:=10pt; % height

label(btex $C$ etex, (0,0));
label(btex $B$ etex, (u,0));
label(btex $A$ etex, (2u,0));


drawarrow ((s,0)--(u-s,0)) shifted (0,-h);
drawarrow ((s,0)--(u-s,0)) shifted (0,h);
drawarrow ((u+s,0)--(2u-s,0)) shifted (0,-h);
drawarrow ((u+s,0)--(2u-s,0)) shifted (0,h);

label.top(btex $\strut S$ etex, (0.5u,h));
label.bot(btex $\strut T$ etex, (0.5u,-h));

drawarrow ((0.5u,0.8h)--(0.5u,-0.8h));
label.rt(btex $\strut\tau$ etex, (0.5u,0));

label.top(btex $\strut S'$ etex, (1.5u,h));
label.bot(btex $\strut T'$ etex, (1.5u,-h));

drawarrow ((1.5u,0.8h)--(1.5u,-0.8h));
label.rt(btex $\strut\tau'$ etex, (1.5u,0));
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I really like the way this output looks, very close to the original! I don't know much (=anything) about metapost. Do I understand correctly that I'd have to compile this metapost code using an external tool and then include the resulting image into my latex file?

Comment: It seems that one can use the `luamplib` package do include the code directly in the document. But then one has to use the more recent lualatex. Let me finally provide a link to the MetaPost manual (http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) in case you want to learn more about MetaPost.

Comment: Update: There seems to be some packages (`mpgraphics` and `gmp`) that enables you to put the code in your tex document.

Comment: Aha, ok. Frankly, my current need isn't so serious as to make me look into a whole new language (metapost), but I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3):

With stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\xtnd{-\kern-5pt-\kern-5pt}
\setstackgap{L}{.45\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[C
\mathop{\raisebox{1pt}{\Centerstack{
  S\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\tau$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\
  T}}}
B
\mathop{\raisebox{1pt}{\Centerstack{
  S'\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\tau'$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\
  T'}}}
A\]
\[C
\mathop{\Centerstack{
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\sigma$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\tau$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow}}
B
\mathop{\Centerstack{
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\sigma'$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow\\ 
  \raisebox{.5pt}{$\scalebox{.8}{$\downarrow$}\scriptstyle\tau'$}\\
  \xtnd\rightarrow}}
A\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, looks like this has a good chance working in my setting. (tikz-cd doesn't seem to work well with latex + dvipng, which is what I'm forced to use). Thanks!